Modificar post_max_size y upload_max_filesize en php-fpm
tengo a mi api corriendo en un contenedor, y no estoy logrando modificar su post_max_size y su upload_max_filesize desde el dockerfile, no logro encontrar el php.ini para modificarlo mismo desde el dockerfile
FROM php:8.2.11-fpm

Encontré estos pero no son los que usa:
    RUN sed -i 's/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 200M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
RUN sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 200M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development
RUN sed -i 's/memory_limit = 128M/memory_limit = 512M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-development

RUN sed -i 's/post_max_size = 8M/post_max_size = 200M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production
RUN sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize = 2M/upload_max_filesize = 200M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production
RUN sed -i 's/memory_limit = 128M/memory_limit = 512M/' /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production


La solución fue:

Creo un archivo php.ini con los datos que quiero que se modifiquen en el contenedor
Agrego lo siguiente en el dockerfile COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
Creo nuevamente la imagen

